# C++ Error converting basic_string to bool

Tags: c++, string, boolean

Hello This may be a simple question and I am sorry for consuming your time for such a simple question but I am trying to learn c++. The following is a small program I am just practicing on as I learn. I have hit a snag in the code as when I execute it I get the following error: " In function 'int main()':

20:19: error: no match for 'operator!' (operand type is 'const string {aka const std::basic_string}')
20:19: note: candidate is:
20:19: note: operator!(bool) 
20:19: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const string {aka const std::basic_string}' to 'bool'

Further below you will find all of my code Thank you for the help!
        #include 
        #include

```
    using namespace std;

int main()
{
const string go = "tomato";
string Answer;

cout << "What is your friends favorite food?" << endl;
cout << "ENTER HERE:" << " " << flush;
cin >> Answer;


if(Answer == go)
{
    cout << "Congratulations you know your friend!!!" << endl;
}
while(Answer =! go)
{
    cout << "What is your friends favorite food?" << endl;
    cout << "ENTER HERE:" << " " << flush;
    cin >> Answer;

    cout << "You do not know your friend please try again!!!" << endl;


}






return 0;
```

}

Comment: You might mean `!=`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Answer =! go` means `Answer = (!go)`. The negation of `go` is undefined, as `go` is not bool.

What you probably want is a comparison for 'not equal', which is `!=`. The sequence of the two characters *is* significant.

Answer (score 0):

The inequality comparison operator is `!=`, and not `=!`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this (in particular change the `=!` to `!=`

```
    using namespace std;

int main()
{
const string go = "tomato";
string Answer;

cout << "What is your friends favorite food?" << endl;
cout << "ENTER HERE:" << " " << flush;
cin >> Answer;


if(Answer == go)
{
    cout << "Congratulations you know your friend!!!" << endl;
}
while(Answer != go)
{
    cout << "What is your friends favorite food?" << endl;
    cout << "ENTER HERE:" << " " << flush;
    cin >> Answer;

    cout << "You do not know your friend please try again!!!" << endl;


}






return 0;
```

Comment: Yeah I knew it was a really stupid mistake Thanks everyone!!

Comment: @Lions654321 It happens to everyone :) Please accept an answer that you liked as well!